# Was my protecting this question appropriate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, protected-question

I saw that a new answer popped up to this old question:

- [What would really happen if you were exposed to space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/what-would-really-happen-if-you-were-exposed-to-space)

I'm pretty sure that this question would be closed as off-topic if it were asked today, since it asks about real-world science, a topic that's repeatedly been accepted as off-topic. But it's a four year-old question, with many highly-voted answers.

However, there's no reason for it to draw *new* answers at this point, even good ones. My first instinct was to protect it, so at least we won't get new answers from random bypassers. Is this a good solution? Is this what we want to use question protection for?

Additionally, should we close this question so even higher-rep users won't contribute new answers to a question that is, at most, tolerated as legacy?

Answer (score 11):

The correct approach for dealing with this type of question is a [Historical Lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for).

From the Meta.SE post:

> A historical lock is a mechanism by which moderators can mark posts as historical artifacts.
>
> A historical lock preserves older content that was very popular when it was originally posted, but is now off-topic or otherwise out of scope for the site it is posted on. Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted, and is often the final state of a question that has been deleted and undeleted more than once.

Going further into the criteria for applying a Historical Lock, this specific question meets all of them:

1. **The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive**.
   I don't think we need to argue about that; most of us would VTC this question if we saw it in the review queue today.
2. **The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature**.
   The number of highly voted answers is evidence of this.
3. **There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post**.
   Over 6000 views and still active today.
4. **The post is contentious; i.e. it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once**.
   The comments provide evidence that the question had attracted close votes, but yet there are none registered for it now.  Therefore it must have gone through the close/reopen cycle at least once.

I've flagged it accordingly.

Comment: And now it's locked.

Answer (score 3):

While protecting the question didn't do anything adverse, it does seem largely unnecessary.

Protecting a question sets a minimum reputation requirement of 10 points to be able to answer the question. None of the answers posted to the question were posted by low-rep users. The newest answer is by a user with over 1,000 rep.

The purpose of protecting a question is to stem an influx of poor answers, which hasn't been an issue on this question *yet*.

Show we close the question? I'd vote to close if it came through the queue. It's not currently on-topic, as it requests an explanation of real-world science. Just because it was once on-topic, it doesn't mean it currently is. Similarly, there have been a few instances when we've re-opened questions that were closed for now-outdated reasons.

Comment: We've got plenty of 'is this possible?' questions that combine sci-fi and real world science, which aren't closed.

Comment: I read the question as more asking "what *would* happen?" and just mentioning the movies as examples of how it's been handled in movies. A fine line, for sure, but one I'd come down on the "VTC" side of.

Comment: @Keen - This one seems pretty damn science-y to me. Not science fiction-y.